# I want to use a Matlab commands From a website on Visual C# web form

Tags: javascript, c#, matlab

Pardon for my programming knowledge. For example for a console application on matlab from Visual C#, we can create a variable of matlab. Like MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); And we can call a execute command like, matlab.execute();

How to use such commands in a web form. I had seen i can also use java script in Visual C# web form. so calling those commands in any language with in a web form helps me.

Thank you.

Comment: This can be done in dozen ways. Check some ASP.NET tutorials (Web forms IMHO is easier to understand then MVC ) - they are quite easy to implement or if you are skilled in javascript check Web Api. This lesson should be enough for your goal: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the required result.... Lots of thanks...